# apk package name modification

Tags: android, filenames, apk

I have created a very basic application and published it to the android market in the past (example: 'com.someapp.theapp'). I have created a new app (version2.0) and manifest shows the app name as com.someapp; is there a way to modify the manifest so it matches the appname of the app I am replacing in google play?

Here is the error message I receive: "The upgraded apk's package name (com.someapp.) must be the same as the one it is replacing (com.someapp.theapp)."

So, what I am trying to accomplish is to take com.someapp and all "theapp" to the end of the src and gen names. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you have to do is refactoring your package name. Do this by right-clicking your package, then refactor, rename and name it: "com.someapp.theapp"